# Rust command line script

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, command-line-tool

Not sure how to run the test image script here

https://github.com/cessen/lut_extractor

Does it require certain dependencies?

Apologies if it's black and white in the readme but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried and what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've cloned the repository and entered it in a command line:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/cessen/lut_extractor.git
cd lut_extractor
```

generate the test image using 'cargo':

```bash
cargo run -- --test-image
```

If you followed these steps, the test image will be available in the 'lut_extractor' folder, named 'lut_extractor_2560x1440.exr'.

You'll need git and cargo to run these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line to install rust (MAC) (copy the entire line)

"curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh"

You will also need to verify installation

"rustc --version"

"cargo --version"

After that your rust is completely set up, clone the repository in the command line:

"git clone [https://github.com/cessen/lut_extractor.git"](https://github.com/cessen/lut_extractor.git%22)

To run anything using Rust, the command is "cargo run" and for you, the command is

"cargo -- --test-image"